# Wildcard search in array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have an array containing a bunch of common terms used to denote that the field is awaiting a PO. Then I have a loop to go backwards through a large column of data deleting any rows where the value in the cell doesn't match any of the terms in the array. To do this I use a function (which I found online) to test if the value exists in the array.

So far so good, as long as the value in the cell matches a value in the array exactly. Where it goes wrong is if a cell contains a slight variation on one of the common terms (ie. "TBC - will follow later" or even just "TBC " instead of "TBC" exactly)

I need a way to take the value in the cell and do a wildcard search against the values in the array. I won't paste all my code (it's a mid-development mess right now), but if we can get this below to work I can apply it.

```
Sub TestFilterArray()
MyArray = Array("tbc", "awaiting po", "po to follow")
If IsInArray("tbc xyz", MyArray) = False Then
    MsgBox "No! Item is not in the array"
Else
    MsgBox "Yes! Item is in the array"
End If
End Sub

Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsInArray = UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1
End Function
```

This currently returns "No!..." for "tbc xyz" not being in the array but I'd like it to return "Yes!..." for "tbc*" being there if that makes sense.

Any help gratefully appreciated.

Comment: What rules do you want to use for partial matching?  For example, if `stringToBeFound` is just `po`, should that return `True` or `False`?  If it is to return `True`, then which words in the multi-word phrases in `MyArray`do we consider and which do we ignore?

Comment: Thanks for jumping in to help @RonRosenfeld A very good point! Ideally the whole string in stringToBeFound should be accounted for with a wildcard at either end. So "awaiting po - xyz" would return true but "awaiting xyz po" would return false.

Comment: See code in my Answer

Comment: The strings in `MyArray` are _contains_ search terms, so we're checking if the value in `StringToBeFound` _contains_ any of the strings stored in `MyArray` within. So "po" in `stringToBeFound` would return `False` as "po" doesn't _contain_ "awaiting po" or "po to follow". "123 awaiting po" would return `True` as the string "123 awaiting po" _contains_ the string "awaiting po". Hope that helps..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Function IsInArray2(StringToBeFound As String, MyArray As Variant) As Boolean
IsInArray2 = False
For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
    If "*" & MyArray(i) & "*" Like StringToBeFound Then IsInArray2 = True 'will match MyArray to any substring of StringToBeFound
Next
End Function
```

With runtime considerations in mind it becomes

```
Function IsInArray2(StringToBeFound As String, MyArray As Variant) As Boolean
IsInArray2 = False
For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
    If "*" & MyArray(i) & "*" Like StringToBeFound Then
        IsInArray2 = True 'will match MyArray to any substring of StringToBeFound
        Exit Function
    End If
Next
End Function
```

Thank you for the remark. Looking back, yep the `Like` statement works the other way around, sorry. Let me make up for it with a case and redundancy matcher and a test to show its importance.

```
Function IsInArray2(stringToBeFound As String, MyArray As Variant) As Boolean
IsInArray2 = False
For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
    If LCase(stringToBeFound) Like LCase("*" & Replace(MyArray(i), " ", "*") & "*") Then
        IsInArray2 = True 'will match MyArray to any substring of StringToBeFound
        Exit Function
    End If
Next
End Function

Sub TestFilterArray()
MyArray = Array("coca cola gmbh", "awaiting po", "po to follow")
If IsInArray2("Coca Cola Deutschland GmbH", MyArray) = False Then
    MsgBox "No! Item is not in the array"
Else
    MsgBox "Yes! Item is in the array"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this! That looks great and I can see how it should work, but for some reason it's still returning "No!...". Stepping through, at the if statement, it doesn't return true on the Like operator so skips past the Then to the Next... Any ideas?

Comment: Stripped back to it's basic level, the following in the immediate window returns "no" -  If "*tbc*" Like "tbc " Then MsgBox "Yes" Else MsgBox "no"

Answer (score 2):

This code seems to do what you require:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestFilterArray()
Dim MyArray As Variant
MyArray = Array("tbc", "awaiting po", "po to follow")
If arrMatch("tbc xyz", MyArray) = False Then
    MsgBox "No! Item is not in the array"
Else
    MsgBox "Yes! Item is in the array"
End If
End Sub

    Function arrMatch(stringToSearch As String, Arr As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim sS As String, sF As String
    Dim I As Long

sS = " " & Trim(stringToSearch) & " "
For I = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
    sF = "*" & Trim(Arr(I)) & "*"
    If sS Like sF Then
        arrMatch = True
        Exit Function
    End If
Next I

arrMatch = False
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks @ronrosenfeld that works great with the given parameters. However, when I change `if arrMatch("tbc xyz"` to `if arrMatch("tbc-xyz"` I'm back to a no-match...

Comment: It was not clear to me from your specifications that you wanted to also match strings in MyArray when they were part of a longer string.  But that's easy to change.

Comment: Thanks again for this @ronrosenfeld. This works great and so does the other fellow's answer. I wish I could pick both as the correct answer!