# Wildcard vlookup in arrays - VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, vlookup

I have a problem to vlookup values from one array into another.

Arrays are:

[image]

---

[image]

My code results in Error 2042:

```
Dim arr9 As Variant
ReDim arr9(LBound(arr7) + UBound(arr7))
i = 0
For i = LBound(arr7) To UBound(arr7) Step 1
arr9(i) = Application.VLookup(Left(arr7(i), 5) & "*", Arr, 1, 0)
Next i
```

[image]

What I need is to find items from arr7, i.e. arr7(0) = zch20 in Arr and assign corresponding value from arr to arr9. Just first 5 characters need to be vlookuped since they are mutual characters for both arr and arr7 but full name string needs to be inserted to arr9.

Thank  you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`VLOOKUP`](https://support.microsoft.com/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) is a worksheet function, for use with ranges of cells (or worksheet [tables](https://support.microsoft.com/office/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c)) but not for VBA [arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-arrays).

A comparable VBA function that you might have more luck with is [`Filter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filter-function).

> `Filter(sourcearray, match, [ include, [ compare ]])`

---

### More info:

- Documentation: [**`Filter` function**](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filter-function)
- Microsoft support: [**VLOOKUP: When and how to use it**](https://support.microsoft.com/office/video-vlookup-when-and-how-to-use-it-9a86157a-5542-4148-a536-724823014785) (video)
- AutomateExcel.com: [**VBA Search for (Find) Value in Array**](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/find-value-in-array/)
- Stack Overflow: [**Wildcard search in array**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30175061/8112776)

Comment: Thank you, tested and it did find what I needed, however it was inserting results into "subarray" arr(9)(0)(0).

Comment: @Thayskills you can acces the first element of the filter and just safe that with `Filter(sourcearray, match, [ include, [ compare ]])(0)`